# Invalid object name sysservers

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2. This is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM sysservers
```

It works fine when I execute it in SQL Server but when I use the query in VB.net this error comes out:

> Invalid object name 'syservers'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `sysservers` anymore - this is a 2000 system table that is only still provided for backward compatibility reasons. You should be using `sys.servers` and you might want to be explicit about where to find it as well:

```
SELECT * FROM master.sys.servers;
```

Comment: could you please add an aliasing workaround to make it possible to resolve the name sysservers without manually adding the master.sys. prefix?

Comment: @F.I.V You can possibly leave out `master` but you need at least the `sys` prefix, sorry. You could create a synonym called `servers` that would avoid it, but why? And you can't create a synonym called `sysservers` because that will call `master.sys.sysservers` no matter what you try to point it at.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Well, in SSMS 18 when trying to browse publications of a remote SQL2008 during the subscription creation wizard, it will raise that invalid object name error and prevents from creation of that subscription. Some other versions combos work correctly as tested in same scenario. Maybe some inaccurate expectation hardcoded in SSMS18 regarding interaction with SQL2008. (oh and I know the EOSL fact:))

Comment: @F.I.V if you’re going to continue using an unsupported database platform, maybe you should keep around an unsupported version of SSMS that will be more compatible...